# Is there a technical reason why the implementation isn't just impl Foo<T>?

Tags: generics, syntax, rust

I just learned that structs using generics are declared as `struct Foo<T>`, and that the implementation is declared as `impl<T> Foo<T>`. The [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-01-syntax.html) explains the discrepancy in the following way:

> Note that we have to declare `T` just after `impl` in order to use `T` in the type `Point<T>`. Declaring `T` as a generic type after the `impl` is how Rust knows the type in the angle brackets in `Point` is a generic type rather than a concrete type.

Again, I'm a newbie, but couldn't the same argument be made for having to declare `struct<T> Foo<T>` (and possibly even `fn<T> foo<T>(bar: T)`)?

Comment: Going by [Rust By Example](https://rustbyexample.com/generics/impl.html), I'm guessing it's because `impl Foo<T>` already means something else: "implement the Foo generic type for one specific type, called T".

Comment: Imagine the situation in reverse: does `impl Foo<i32>` mean "implementation of Foo for 32-bit integers", or "generic implementation of Foo for any type parameter named `i32`"? This ambiguity doesn't in the other cases you mention.

Comment: @millimoose: So in some cases `<>` denotes a generic, and in some a specific type? It seems it would be difficult to know which one I'm dealing with without being familiar with the syntax.

Comment: It's no more confusing than `(...)` being both how you define and how you call a function.  And I'm not sure how you'd be effective in *any* language if you're unfamiliar with its syntax.

Comment: Fair enough, of course. Rust otherwise has a very clear syntax, but I guess this sort of ambiguity is too much rooted in the C++ tradition. I guess we don't have enough different brackets to distinguish this clearly :)

Comment: @l0b0 Suppose we used `«»` for declaring a generic and `<>` for using a specific type -- then you'd have to write `struct Foo«T»` and `impl«T» Foo<T>`. Would that really make things clearer?

Comment: Actually it might. Hmm.

Comment: @trentcl That's exactly what I meant - making it obvious what's a generic and what's a specific type, regardless of context.

Comment: @l0b0, every time I write `impl«T»`, I will be thinking "Is it `«` or `<`? Ah, what's the matter, let it be `<`. Compiler will tell me if I wrong." Why introduce a choice where it is not needed?  `impl«T»`, `impl<T>`, `impl[T]`, `impl(T)` - those can't mean anything other than "declare generic type T".

Comment: @red75prime You could make the same argument for using brackets for everything. The compiler will be able to tell from context what you meant. That doesn't mean it's not confusing.

Comment: @l0b0, no, I can't. `impl` provides an anchor which unambiguously defines a meaning of nearby `T`, while I perceive `<>` as generic enclosure for a list of types. `struct` provides another anchor. In something like `fn foo(t)(a:t) -> ((t)a(a))` there's no apparent anchors.

Comment: @red75prime The point was that you could easily define a *more* ambiguous syntax by overloading the meaning of whatever character(s) you choose, or you could make a *less* ambiguous syntax than the current one by having a different syntax for generic and specific types. There's no reason your example syntax could be unambiguous to a compiler, while being impenetrable to a programmer.

Comment: While you’re correct about the ambiguity being there, every single language with generics has the ambiguity, which might be why the designers of Rust didn’t think it’s confusing to rely on context. E.g. in C#, in `class List<T> : IList<T> {`, the angle brackets have both meanings, vs. `interface IList<T>` or `class IntList : IList<int>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
impl Foo<T> { ... }
```

Is `T` a type parameter, or an actual type named `T`?  If you answered the second, then you've thrown generics out the window entirely: it would be impossible to implement functionality for a generic set of types.  If you answered the first, then how do you propose users do this:

```
impl Foo<T> { /* generic stuff */ }
impl Foo<i32> { /* i32-specific stuff */ }
impl Foo<u32> { /* u32-specific stuff */ }
```

That would just be three `impl` blocks with type parameters named `T`, `i32`, and `u32` respectively.

You might say "well, just decide from context".  Now, in order to work out what's going on, a user has to check not only the rest of the module, but all imported symbols *and* anything in the standard library's prelude in order to decide if a type is a parameter or not.  Rust abhors this kind of ambiguity.

It is far, *far* simpler for the compiler and the reader to just be specific about what is and is not a parameter.

You don't have to do this with `struct` because the thing in the brackets cannot possibly be anything *other* than a type parameter declaration.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies it. I guess my confusion stemmed from the ambiguity that *sometimes* `<T>` means a generic, and sometimes a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@dk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42353/dk)'s answer, I would like to compare how Rust does it to how Haskell does it.

In Haskell, all specific types must start capitalized. Thus, it is illegal to write:

```haskell
data mytype Var = Constructor {
    myVar :: Var,
    myInt :: Foo
}
```

Instead, Haskell reserves types which start with a lower-cased letter for type variables:

```haskell
data MyType var = Constructor {
     myVar :: var
     myInt :: Int
}

instance MyClass (MyType var) where
     ...
```

Here, `var` is a type variable, `MyType` is concrete, and `Int` is concrete.

In my opinion - which you may not share, Rust made the mistake to allow non-capitalized type-identifiers. Thus the language has no other choice but to require you to explicitly say which type identifiers are variables and which are specific. An argument could be made that Rust's explicitness improves readability. The opposite could also be argued.

Rust could of course add a hypothetical feature where you may say:

```
 impl Foo<#T, T, u32> { .. }
```

Here, the prefix `#` is taken to mean "This is a type variable", so `#T` is a type variable, `T` is specific, and `u32` is specific. There is no ambiguity and only local reasoning is required.

With this feature, you may get a little bit less verbosity, but I firmly believe this ship has sailed - adding this feature now will only add another way of doing the same thing for very little gain. The feature would however add the cost of having another feature that the language users must learn.

Comment: Great comparison and summary of the issue!